# optimized pairing of weighted pixels in an image

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Given a matrix X that represents an image, each pixel X(i,j) has a vector Vij that gives the cost of associating pixel X(i,j) with every other pixel in the image (I will actual use it for a specified small neighborhood but it shouldn't make a difference algorithmic-wise).

The cost of pairing pixels X(i,j) and X(k,p) is the combined cost of associating pixel X(i,j) with X(k,p) and the cost of associating pixel X(k,p) with pixel X(i,j). Note that the cost function is symmetric, i.e. the cost of association X(i,j) with X(k,p) is equal to the cost of associating X(k,p) with X(i,j).

The goal is to find a pairing for each pixel in the image such that every pixel is part of exactly one pairing and the total cost is minimized/maximized.

2D spatial locality has no special significance, so we could consider `X[i*w + j]` as a 1D array of costs, and construct a 2D cost matrix.  Given the symmetry, we can consider only the half of the matrix above the diagonal.  We're then looking for a set of points (row,column pairs) with the minimum total sum.  Each row and column can only be used once.  (Including `C[a][b]` eliminates all entries in row `a` and all entries in column `b` from being possible other members of the solution set.)

One method that comes to mind is to treat it as a flow problem, but in that case I'm at loss as to how to construct the graph.

Comment: It sounds like a close variant of the travelling salesman problem to me, which is known to be NP-hard  With that in mind, you may be better off looking for a method which gives you a solution which is within some tolerance of optimal, which is how the TSP is usually handled.

Comment: Does the cost matrix have any properties that might help?  e.g. is the `A -> B` cost at all related to the `B -> A` cost?

Comment: Peter Cordes - The cost function is in fact symetric, i.e. C(X(i,j), X(k,p)) = C(X(k,p), X(i,j)). I will add this information to the original posting

Comment: @user969289: use @ username in comments to make sure people get notified of replies.  (It doesn't happen automatically unless the comment is under their post).  The symmetry means you only need the upper or lower half of the matrix (above or below the diagonal), I guess.  I assume the diagonal itself (pairing a pixel with itself) has effectively infinite cost (i.e. not allowed).

Comment: Err, I was thinking 1D, which would work if you consider the pixels as a linear array.  There's nothing in your requirements that changes if every pixel only has one index.  It makes no difference that `X(i-1, j)` is next to `X(i,j)`, so you could just index them as `X[ i*W + j ]` and consider costs as a 2D matrix, rather than 4D.  IDK if this helps any!

Comment: @peterCordes, I assume your suggestion leads to an integer programming solution?

Comment: @user969289: sorry no, I ran out of ideas after that; it's not an area of algorithms I'm experienced with.  I just hoped to give you and potential answerers the idea of looking at costs as a 2D matrix, in case it leads somewhere useful, or turned this into a well-known problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your goal correctly, your problem is essentially finding the perfect matching with maximum/minimum weight in a weighted graph.

Links to read:

- [Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Definition)
- [Maximal matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#cite_note-blossom5-10)
- [Kolmogorov's minimal matching algorithm](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/blossom5.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I keep thinking of video encoding methods for this (search for a local-minimum solution of how to encode this block), and then move on.  Use early-outs to eliminate potential candidates as quickly as possible.

The only case where the optimal solution is obvious is when the minimum cost in each row is in a different column.

I came up with a fast algorithm that will find a solution, and a refinement step it can do along the way.  I made this up from scratch, not directly based on anything, so there are probably lots of clever ideas I've missed.  I don't see a way to extend my algorithm to a find globally-optimal solution, so this might not be what you're looking for at all, if local-minima solutions aren't useful for you.  It should be fast, though, in terms of number of operations and also memory-access pattern.

**Linear time, one-pass no refinement**.  I hope still better-than-random solution for most possible cost distributions.

```c
N = width*height;  // number of pixels in the image
int C[N][N] = costs;
int pair[N];
bitmap used[N] = { 0 };
// every iteration pairs two pixels, so we only need N/2 iterations.
for (int r=0 ; r<N/2 ; r++) {
    if (used[r])
        continue;
    // elements < r are already paired, so only check the potential candidates: from r+1 onwards
    int minpos = mincost_unused_position(C[r][r+1 .. N], used);
    pair[r] = minpos;
    pair[minpos] = r;
    used[r] = used[minpos] = 1;
}
```

This will get *a* solution, but not an optimal solution.  It searches costs only on one side of the diagonal, because all elements `< r` have already been paired.  You could also save time by not bothering to update `used[r]` or `pair[minpos]`, since all the information is there from the other updates.

If you want to get closer to an optimal solution, then consider all the costs in every row, not just the unused ones.  If the min cost is lower than the min unused cost, then check if the wanted min cost can be freed up by re-pairing the pixel *it* was paired with.

**Linear time, with a refinement step**.  The amount of refinement work, and amount of memory touched during refinement, is tightly bounded (by a tunable constant).

```c
// ALMOST CERTAINLY FULL OF BUGS, but I hope it gets the idea across
N = width*height;  // number of pixels in the image
int C[N][N] = costs;
int pair[N];
bitmap used[N] = { 0 };  // or just initialize pair[] to -1 in every element, and check it.

// cache the 8 least-cost pairings for every point.  8 is a tunable constant.
// One array of struct { int pos, cost; }; might be better for cache, esp. if this can't vectorize.
int mincost_positions[N][8];
int mincost_costs[N][8];    // sorted in order of increasing cost

for (int r=0 ; r<N/2 ; r++) {
    int minpos, min_unused_pos;
    int non_optimal = min_search(C[r][0 .. N], used, &minpos, &min_unused_pos, &mincost_positions[r][0], &mincost_costs[r][0]);
    used[r] = true;  // exclude r as a candidate for re-pairing
    if (non_optimal) {
        int wanted = mincost_positions[r][0];  // also = minpos;
        int wantcost_r = mincost_costs[r][0];

        // attempt to re-pair minpos to free it up for us
        int wpair = pair[wanted];
        assert (wpair < r || wanted < r);  // we can't have paired two elements we haven't yet reached
        // if (wpair > r) swap(wpair, wanted);  // mincost_positions and costs haven't been filled out yet for pixels beyond our current position.  (unless we do that in a separate parallelizable first-stage)

        int current_cost = C[wanted][wpair] + C[r][min_unused_pos];  // cost of current pairing for the element we want + cost of best available pairing for r
            // TODO:  more cache-friendly: search mincost_costs instead of touching C[]

        // mincost_positions is sorted in order of lowest cost
        // so the first available alternative pairing for wpair will give the lowest total cost.

        for (int alt=0 ; alt<8 ; alt++) {
            int trypos = mincost_positions[wpair][alt];  // find the next-lowest-cost unused pairing that will free up the pixel we want.

            if (!used[trypos]) {
                int altcost = mincost_costs[wpair][alt] + wantcost_r;

                if (altcost < current_cost) {
                    // re-pair wpair with its next-best option
                    pair[wpair] = trypos;
                    pair[trypos] = wpair;
                    used[trypos] = true;
                    min_unused_pos = wanted;
                } // else nothing

                break;  // early-out, because mincost_costs[wpair][alt] is just going to get worse.
            }
        }
    }
    pair[r] = min_unused_pos;
    pair[min_unused_pos] = r;

    used[min_unused_pos] = true;
    // used[r] = true;   // already done earlier, to cover the trypos == r case.
}
```

Memory is still mostly read contiguously, making good use of most of a cache line when it's needed.  `used[]` should fit in cache, since it's a bitmap.  `pair[]` isn't touched very often, and might fit in cache.  There's a stray `C[wanted][wpair]`, which could be eliminated by a linear search in `mincost_positions[wanted][]` for `wpair`, then using the index where it was found as an index into `mincost_costs[wanted][]`

It should be possible to fill out the `mincost_positions[] and costs[]` caches in parallel, with threads, and then not have to touch `C[][]`.  This could be a win if C is way too big to fit in the cache.  Also, it might work well with your proposed local-area-only cost search.

Otherwise, maybe only cache min-cost positions, instead of actual costs, if the code is going to touch `C` at those places anyway (to avoid linear-searching the `mincost_positions` array when we want a cost by position instead of by rank).

We could consider more possibilities by checking if freeing up the next-best pairing for `r` is helpful.  (Add another loop around the `wanted` / `wpair` loop that checks `for each wanted in mincost_positions[r][0..n]` (until `wanted == min_unused_pos`)).  Remember which swap candidate gave the lowest net cost, and do it.

Doing another refinement pass isn't really possible, since there are no alternatives for re-pairing anything.  You could descent the tree of mincost_positions, and if you found a loop, that would indicate there is a set of points that could all be repaired at the same time.  This gets into `O(n * m^d)` time, where `m` is the size of the mincost_positions cache, and `d` is the max depth of searching this "tree" for loops.

### completely different ideas

I also wondered if maybe some linear algebra techniques could be applied to transform the 2D cost matrix?  Would https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination produce any kind of useful matrix where the optimal set of pairs is easier to find?